# Can't get code to run on startup in init.d file

Tags: linux, bash, boot

Been working at this for literally over 4 hours. All I'm trying to do is get the following code to run at startup:

```
IP_ADDR=$(/sbin/ifconfig eth0 | /bin/sed -rn 's/^.*inet addr:(([0-9]+\.){3}[0-9]+).*$/\1/p')
/usr/bin/wget -q -O /dev/null http://example.com/private/RPi_IP.php?send=${IP_ADDR}
```

With example.com replaced with my website. For some reason every time on startup I get a message that the startup file I made failed. I have no clue what to do. I even tried writing this code into other startup files for other programs, and it still causes it to fail. Is there anything really wrong with this code? It works fine as a stand alone bash script, but not on startup.

After I make the file that I put this in I always do:

```
chmod +x file
sudo update-rc.d file defaults
```

Is there something wrong with what I am doing above? I am on a Raspberry Pi with Raspbian if that is useful.

Comment: Does your file contain those two lines and nothing else? Could you show us the error message you get?

Comment: Are you sure this file is executed after the ethernet connection is established? If it is not, it is easy to understand its failure. To check on this, you may insert these two lines of code at the end of /etc/rc.local, preceded by something like sleep 30, just to make sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than making it into a startup script, if you only need it to run on reboot, I would use cron instead.
`@reboot /path/to/file` will make it run on startup.
The scripts in init.d need particular lines and whatnot, and if you don't need all that faff then cron does the job just fine.